# Simplifying Trig Product in terms of a single expression and $n$

Tags: trigonometry, trigonometric-series

I participated in a math competition at a nearby university yesterday, and there was one ciphering problem that no one correctly simplified.

As the title suggests, we were asked to simplify the following trigonometric product such that it was in terms of a single expression (sine/cosine) and $n$.

$$\sin(x)\prod_{i=0}^n\cos(2^ix)$$

Typically with problems like these, which must be solved in under two minutes, the expression is telescoping in some manner that allows one to quickly simplify or solve it. This was how I approached it but simply didn't have enough time to see if it would work.

I know one of the professors, and he said the problem may be simplified using a number of double-angle formulas, but I'm still unsure how this method would work.

Could someone show how they might approach simplifying such an expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\sin(x)\prod_{i=0}^n\cos(2^ix)=\sin(x)\cos(x)\cos(2x)\cos(4x)...\cos(2^nx)= \\ =\frac{\sin(2x)}{2}\cos(2x)\cos(4x)...\cos(2^nx)= \\ =\frac{\sin(4x)}{4}\cos(4x)...\cos(2^nx)=...= \\ = \frac{\sin(2^{n+1}x)}{2^{n+1}}$$

Comment: Fantastic answer, thank you!

Comment: anytime ;) interesting question anyway! could you supply some more details about the math competition you mention in your post?

Comment: Sure. It's for high schools in Georgia and consists of an individual exam portion and a ciphering portion. Each school has 8 people take the individual exam and the 4 highest scores are totaled. The ciphering consists of two teams of two students, and they are given 10 questions which must each be completed in under 2 minutes (with bonus points for finishing in under 1 minute). At the end of the tournament, team totals for the individual portion and ciphering portion are totaled, and team awards are then given. There are also individual awards for those who do the best on the first portion.

Comment: @KonKan I agree, a most brilliant answer. What was your thought process? How did you know that it would simplify so nicely from left to right? Did you get it quickly ie. it was very intuitive for you? Look forward to hearing your remarks!

Answer (score 3):

Hint: We are looking at 
$$\sin x\cos x\cos 2x\cos 4x\cos 8x\cos 16 x\cdots.$$ This is 
$$\frac{1}{2}\cdot\sin 2x \cos 2x\cos 4x\cos 8x\cos 16x\cdots,$$ which is $$\frac{1}{4}\cdot\sin 4x \cos 4x\cos 8x\cos 16x\cdots.$$ Continue.

Comment: You are welcome.